# Attribute Error while trying to get data from athena view using lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

My code

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import time

def lamda_handler(event,context):
    client=boto3.client('athena')
    
    #Setup and perform query
    queryStart=client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString='SELECT number FROM View LIMIT 10;',
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database':'transformed_db'
        },
        ResResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': 's3://raw-data/AthenaSAP',
        }
    )

#Observe results


queryID=queryStart['QueryExecutionID']
    time.sleep(15)
    
    results=client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionID=queryID)
    for row in results['ResultSet']['Rows']:
        print(row)`enter code here`
```

The error I am getting is:
Response
"errorMessage": "'InvalidRequestException' object has no attribute 'message'",
"errorType": "AttributeError",
"stackTrace": [
"  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 27, in lambda_handler\n    if 'Query has not yet finished' in err.message:\n"

I am trying to read data from athena view and store it into output bucket

Comment: Are you confident that 15s is enough for your query to complete?

Comment: Yes it should complete